# using GIF image on scroll of page

Tags: javascript

How can I animate an image on page scroll in a single page website so that when I scroll to next section it animates? Suppose I am using a closed eye which opens when I scroll to next section.

Comment: you cannot control the playback of a gif in JS, though you can convert into stills and cycle still images...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the libgif library here: https://github.com/buzzfeed/libgif-js

It allows you to start, stop, or advance the gif frame programmatically. Here is an example straight from the source:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./libgif.js"></script>
<img src="./example1_preview.gif" rel:animated_src="./example1.gif" width="360" height="360" rel:auto_play="1" rel:rubbable="1" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $$('img').each(function (img_tag) {
        if (/.*\.gif/.test(img_tag.src)) {
            var rub = new SuperGif({ gif: img_tag } );
            rub.load(function(){
                console.log('oh hey, now the gif is loaded');
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

You can then use a combination of `get_length` (the number of frames in the gif),  `move_to` (to go to a specific frame), and `onscroll` in jQuery/JavaScript to set the frame as the user scrolls your page.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [ScrollMagic](http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/) which specializes in exactly what you are asking. Not sure about gif animations specifically, but they have [tons of examples](http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/examples/index.html) for different element animations.